# Is there a nice way to define whether catch block was run?

Tags: c#

I've got standard try-catch-finally block:

```
try
{
//Action
}
catch(Excteption e)
{
//Catch block
}
finally
{
// Action which would be run in case if catch block was not run
// Action which would be run anyway
}
```

I would like to know if there is a certain way to know if code inside of catch block was run or not, to run a specific code in finally block, please note that I understand that I can create a bool value to put it to the catch block in order to detect it's execution, but this seems rather an ugly way to manage things :)

Please, share your solution, 
thanks :)

Edit:
In the end I used slightly modified version of what Jeroen proposed:

```
Func<string> Action = null;
try
{
Action = () =>
{
//Action
return true;
};
}
catch(Exception e)
{
Action = () =>
{
//Catch block
return false
}
finally
{
if(Action())
//Action which would be run in case if catch block was not run
// Action which would be run anyway
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: _"I understand that I can create a bool value in the catch block "_ No, it must be declared outside

Comment: @TimSchmelter fixed a second before I read a comment :)

Comment: What about moving the `// Action which would be run in case if catch block was not run` up into the `try` block, after `//Action` ?

Comment: You could execute `// Action which would be run in case if catch block was not run` at the end of the try block. If it executes, the previous operations clearly executed without an exception.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Aha, my bad. You are absolutely correct. Topic could be deleted as well, seems like I was holding the knife from the wrong side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do exactly what you describe in the comments, but then in C#:

```
Action toBeRun;

try
{
   ...
   toBeRun = () => { ... };
}
catch
{
   toBeRun = () => { ... };
}
finally
{
   toBeRun();
}
```

Comment: Well, this is something, that gave me some experience!
Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: I would only correct one thing:
It should be:
    Action toBeRun = null;

Comment: You could make it `Action toBeRun = () => { };`, so that you don't have to deal with possible NullReferenceExceptions

Comment: But wouldn't I be unable to use this method inside of finally block due it's scope?

Comment: It is declared outside of the try...catch...finally, so you should be able to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your scenario, this is the easiest way to fix your code:

```
try
{
    // Action
    // Action which would be run in case if catch block was not run
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // Catch block
}
finally
{
    // Action which would be run anyway
}
```

Notice that I simply moved your comment up into the `try` block.

If `// Action` does not throw an exception, it will continue executing inside the `try` block.